# Using the default session in Placebo to unit test Boto3 code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have legacy Boto3 code that makes a lot of use of the default Boto3 session, e.g.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')
client.describe_images(DryRun=False)
...
```

I wish to write unit tests for this legacy code using [placebo](https://github.com/garnaat/placebo).

However, docs there seem to imply that the code-under-test would need to always manage the Boto3 session explicitly, i.e.

```
import boto3
import placebo

session = boto3.Session()
pill = placebo.attach(session, data_path='/path/to/response/directory')
pill.record()

client = session.client('ec2')
client.describe_images(DryRun=False)
...
```

My reading of the code ([e.g.](https://github.com/garnaat/placebo/blob/develop/placebo/pill.py#L125-L130)) is that this is quite a limitation of the Placebo Mock framework, although I am no expert Python programmer.

Am I misunderstanding something basic - is there any way to work-around this, or would I have to refactor all my legacy code to explicitly pass around a session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by reading through the Boto3 unit tests ([ref](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/master/tests/unit/test_boto3.py)).

To attach Placebo to the default session, it is necessary to explicitly setup the default session, before calling Placebo:

```
import boto3
import placebo

boto3.setup_default_session()
session = boto3.DEFAULT_SESSION
pill = placebo.attach(session, data_path='/path/to/response/directory')
pill.record()

client = boto3.client('ec2')
client.describe_images(DryRun=False)
```

Now, just by adding those four lines, I can record Boto3 calls in my legacy code, without further refactoring.

I will raise a pull request to add these notes in the Placebo README.

Answer (score 2):

placebo needs a Session object and the examples all show creating an explicit Session object but I think you could just reference the "built-in" Session object.

```
import boto3
import placebo

pill = placebo.attach(boto3.session, data_path='/path/to/response/directory')
```

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks so much. If it works, I'll send a PR to clarify the docs.

Comment: No, that's not working - I'll update the issue in your project showing the details.